# I want to create Jmeter script in which I can provide delay between dependent API calls dynamically

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I want to create Jmeter script in which some api calls are made only after the response of the api calls which it is dependent upon is received successfully. Is it possible in Jmeter? And if yes then please let me know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each JMeter Thread (virtual users) is executing samplers upside down (or according to [Logic Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)) so given you have [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers like:

- HTTP Request 1
- HTTP Request 2
- HTTP Request 3
- etc.

Each JMeter thread will execute samplers **sequentially** so you basically don't do anything.

**Unless** you are trying to synchronize Threads running in the different [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group), in that case you need to implement some synchronization between them so the threads which depend on previous results would wait until they are executed. You can implement it using [Inter-Thread Communication](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) plugin for setting up synchronization.

You can install Inter-Thread Communication Plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Inter Thread Communication]